# CMAKE create OSX bundle for dylib?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I need some help from from someone that unlike me actually knows something about CMAKE.

Problem:
I have this CMAKE project that produces a .so/.dylib/.dll (its a plugin for another application) and so far everything is fine it's  compiling and linking and produces the expected output. It's setup to build as a MODULE like this:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} MODULE ${CORE_SRC} ${CORE_HEADERS})
```

with a healthy bunch of external dependencies and a few compiler/linker settings.

And builds using two custom targets:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(debug
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target all
        COMMENT "Switch CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Debug")

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(release
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target all
        COMMENT "Switch CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Release")
```

My problem is that on osx this dylib must be packaged as a osx BUNDLE or it wont load. I could create the bundle directory structure manually but with my not so comprehensive CMAKE knowledge I do believe I should be able to have it generated for me. I did try to follow some examples, but I could only get it to work for executable files.

What I would like is to have my dylib installed into a bundle with its resources inside my out of source directory. On other platforms the resources just go into a folder next to the dylib. And then have the bundle installed, or dll and folder, into whatever destination they are destined for.

So how to bundle a module? Is it even possible or am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 4):

this is all quite possible with cmake; tho I remember having a difficult time figuring it all out as well.

I have a rather complex project that does this very thing with a dylib, a framework, and a series of plugins (which happen to also be `.so`s). [Here](https://github.com/gemrb/gemrb/blob/master/gemrb/CMakeLists.txt) is one of its CMakeLists.txt files that covers most of what you need (around line 38).

If you want cmake to crate the bundle for you, you need to pass `MACOSX_BUNDLE` when you add the executable (`ADD_EXECUTABLE`). Note that this is for the Application itself and *not* for the dylib.

If it is possible for you to build the dylib as a framework (`FRAMEWORK` property), cmake *should* automatically put it it the bundle's frameworks directory when you add it. dito for plugins if you build them with the `BUNDLE` property.

you can also [manually assign](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_sf/MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION.html) the `MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION` property to whatever you like

I believe you also may have to do something like `SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH @loader_path/../Frameworks)` on the target.

Let me know if you have any questions and i will update my answer.